# Why is my form auto submitting on page load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have an html form that can auto tab through all the elements in the form. After submitting, it calls the first element (order_number) and the cursor stays in the second field that way someone can scan Multiple (Chip_numbers) with a same order_number.

To reset the whole form, I wanted to refresh the page, but then the error message pops up and the cursor is automatically put in the second element.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
$servername = "host";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "JVSIntranet";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL (chip_number,order_number)
VALUES 
('$_POST[chip_number]','$_POST[order_number]')";

IF (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Great Job! You've entered it correctly!";
} else {
    echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
}

$value = "";
if( isset( $_POST ["order_number"] )) $value = $_POST ["order_number"];

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getNextElement(field) {
    var form = field.form;
    for ( var e = 0; e < form.elements.length; e++) {
        if (field == form.elements[e]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return form.elements[++e % form.elements.length];
}

function tabOnEnter(field, evt) {
if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (evt.stopPropagation) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
        getNextElement(field).focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="document.chip_insert.chip_number.focus();">
<center>
<h1>Jeffers HomeAgain Microchip Entry</h1>


<form name="chip_insert"  id="chip_insert" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" >
Order Number: <input tabindex="1" maxlength="12" type="text" name="order_number"  id="order_number" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"  required="required"onkeydown="return tabOnEnter(this,event)"  /><br /><br />
Tag Number: <input tabindex="2" maxlength="15" type="text" name="chip_number" id="chip_number" required="required" /><br /><br />
<input tabindex="7" type="submit" />
</center>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the initial PHP just loads, nothing is saying to wait the form to load. There is no check to see if you are submitting or not the form.

Comment: you are correct, but i am new to this so i do not know the correct way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some more problems with this code...

```
IF (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 echo "Great Job! You've entered it correctly!";
} else {
 echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
}
```

should be like

```
if(isset($_POST['chip_number'] && $_POST['chip_number'] != '')
{
  IF (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo "Great Job! You've entered it correctly!";
  } else {
   echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
  }
}
```

and

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL (chip_number,order_number)
VALUES 
('$_POST[chip_number]','$_POST[order_number]')";
```

should be some like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL (chip_number,order_number)
VALUES 
('{$_POST['chip_number']}','{$_POST['order_number']}')";
```

and even the last thing isnt the right type to call this...
may you have a look at [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

what actually would be some like

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL VALUES (?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'dd', $_POST['chip_number'], $_POST['order_number']);
//....
mysqli_execute();
```

or

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL SET chip_number=?,order_number=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'dd', $_POST['chip_number'], $_POST['order_number']);
//....
mysqli_execute();
```

these samples are NOT build to an object like $db = new mysqli(...); But you should think about it to use it this way :)

Comment: The manual you linked looks to be mostly German but ill look around some more for it. However, i did edit my code to how you said and the page loads and still submits automatically and now when i try to tab through the elements i get "page not found" error.  So it broke it a little more, i undid those changes for now.

Comment: sorry, but its on php.net so you just have to switch the letters DE to EN so you get this here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, i will edit it in my post. I also edited the if. try to use `$var != ''` instead of `!empty($var)`

Comment: i tried your edited version and the page won't even load now.  I'm at a lost, still not giving up though.

Comment: propably because you getting some errors. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the first line and try it again. What does the page returns ?

Comment: The page loads but when i submit i get "website cannot display the page" even with error_reporting(E_ALL); in the first line

Comment: Maybe this will help, i replaced my action =$php_self with just some random letters to see if it was actually trying to post.  If i hit submit it says "cannot find the file" which is correct.  But when i load the page it still puts the error and starts in the second field without a post error.  So it's just loading like it was but not really trying to post.  If that makes sense

Comment: Yea, no matter if it has if(isset($_POST) it will still display the error and jump down in the second element because it is not actually posting.  It has to be something in my tab or error function when it loads, or in my input line where i call back the first element after submission.

Comment: may you post your total source in [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/) and add this to your post to really see whats going on

Comment: Well i know for sure now it's not submitting, it's just my onLoad function is set to go to my second element for when i submit and i can keep the same order number in the first element and scan multiple tag numbers with it.  The problem i'm having is trying to clear the whole page and put the focus on the first element to start over and refresh/load isn't going to do that because of my onLoad.  All of this has to be done with a scanner.  I suppose i will open a new question. you were right on your comment though, IF it was auto posting.  Thank you for trying Dwza

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you open this page it will make insertion to database no matter if there is post coming or not.
Because there is no post control (is post came or not control) the code blocks below:

```
IF (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 echo "Great Job! You've entered it correctly!";
} else {
 echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
}
```

This part should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  IF (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Great Job! You've entered it correctly!";
  } else {
     echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
 }
}
```

Comment: not really good if you simply ask if post is set. because if you submit the form empty, post IS set ^^

Comment: You are right, checking if the post is empty or not should be added the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Your php section should look like this

```
<?php
$servername = "host";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "JVSIntranet";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$value = "";
if (isset($_POST ["order_number"])) {
    $value = $_POST ["order_number"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL (chip_number,order_number)
VALUES 
('$_POST[chip_number]','$_POST[order_number]')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Great Job! You've entered it correctly!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
    }
}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And in html  `</center>` should be after `</form>` tag though its not big issue

Comment: I tried this but it still auto submitted and displays "page not found" when i simply tab through an element.  I know for a fact that i have to tell the php to wait for the form to submit, i just need the method, i am very much new to this.